# gp_dump utility of greenplum not available

Tags: database-administration, database-backups, greenplum

Can anyone tell me why is the gp_dump utility is not available with greenplum database by default? If I have to use it then what is the source to download and way to enable it?  I have gone through a lot of online resources but nothing relevant could be found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Greenplum v6.x?

The latest version of gpbackup is located here:

https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpbackup/releases

and if interested, the corresponding s3 plugin here: 
https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpbackup-s3-plugin

gp_dump is a very old, deprecated backup utility for Greenplum.

The older python based gpcrondump/gpdbrestore utilities are still bundled in Greenplum 4.3.x and 5.x versions, but do not support Greenplum 6.x and thus removed.

The newer Golang based gpbackup/gprestore utilities support Greenplum 4.3.22 and later, Greenplum 5.5 and later and Greenplum 6.0 and later all in the same binary.

Let me know if you have additional questions.

- oak

Comment: Can we do remote backups through gpbackup utility?

Comment: No, the utility is designed to be executed on the GPDB Master node.

Comment: Then what is the option for me?
Postgres native utility?

Answer (score 0):

Try using pg_dump since Greenplum is a fork of postgres.

Comment: pg_dump is non parallel utility. I want to use greenplum specific things if possible